# order status and state - magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, order-status, order-state

I bit confused utilizing order **status** and **state**. I have created **Delivered** status but unfortunately it get duplicated with two different state. When I rename order status lable of anyone it will automatically affects others also so I am not sure which status is shown in frontend. I am also tried to unassign but it will throw error *can't unassign already orders are used this status*.When I change the order status to **delivered** that order is **not listed** in customer account page, but I need to show delivered status in customer account page.

please refer the below screenshot for your easy reference

[image: easy for your reference]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

> Go **Stores > Order Status** and Click on **Assign status to state** button above show in screenshot and you'll be able to change that.

[image]

#### Important note for Pending Payments

If you have a "pending payment" status order, **Magento 2 will cancel the order automatically after 8 hours** if the payment status doesn't change.

To change that, go to **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Order Cron Settings** and **change the Lifetime to a greater value**.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same doubt and found this post that helped me a lot to understand

See https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/magento-2-order-status/

Maybe help u too !!!

Answer (score 1):

An order state is a position of an order in the curent processing flow.
Magento has the following pre-defines order states:

List item

- New
- Pending Payment
- Processing
- Complete
- Closed
- Canceled
- On Hold
- Payment Review

Each Magento order state can have one or more order statuses assigned to it. This makes processing easier and helps to add some flexibility to order.

For example, a “Pending Payment” order state can have the following order statuses:

- Pending Payment Paypal
- Pending Payment Card
- Pending Payment Store Credit